# commutation relation of angular momentum operator in non cartesian coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, coordinate-systems, quantum-mechanics

The angular momentum operator $J$ in quantum mechanics with the commutation relation

\begin{equation*}
[J_l,J_m]=i\hbar\epsilon_{lmn}J_n
\end{equation*}

has the structure of a *Lie-algebra*. It is easy to see that this commutation relation holds in cartesian coordinates. However, using, e.g., the cylindrical coordinate basis $\{{\bf e}_\rho\,{\bf e}_\varphi,{\bf e}_z\}$, the angular momentum has the form

\begin{equation*}
{\bf J}=i\hbar\left(\frac{z}{\rho}\partial_\varphi{\bf e}_\rho + (\rho\partial_z-z\partial_\rho){\bf e}_\varphi+\partial_\varphi{\bf e}_z\right).
\end{equation*}

Inserting the components naively *in this basis* in the mentioned commutation relation, one can see that it does not hold. How to properly transform the commutation relation in curvilinear coordinates so that the commutation relation holds? (Changing die Levi-Civita symbol by a factor $\sqrt{g}$ is obviously not enough.)

Comment: I assume that the $i$ in $i\hbar\epsilon_{ijk}$ satisfies $i^2=-1$. This is confusing considering the index $i$ used in $[J_i,J_j]$, which I assume lives in $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: @robjohn: Right, changed it.

Comment: Try it for spherical coordinates and note there is only *one* nontrivial commutation relation, *but* the "structure constant" is not constant. That's *why* nobody goes there, even when quadratic Casimirs are involved.